# Hard disk heating and noise issue on Seagate ST500LM000

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, overheating

I have recently got a brand new Seagate ST500LM000 Solid State Hybrid Drive. My old traditional hard disk just failed in my Toshiba Satellite C660 laptop, so I decided to use this SSHD in my laptop. I installed this drive, and it was working very well. But after couple of boots (on the same day), I heard some noise coming from the SSHD. It is really too much noise, and I can even feel the spinning of the disk. Also the drive becomes quite hot.

I really don't know why this is happening. I was installing Windows 8 on my laptop. Is there anything wrong with my new SSHD? Is my new drive defective?

Comment: Have you try to do HDD test? If you go to Seagate website, you can download a program from them to do HDD testing. (I think they call it SeaTools)

Comment: Or use Acronis Drive Monitor. It will tell you drive temps.